# CSS Optimization: Turning page-specific CSS into global?

Tags: css

When starting a new website project, there's only so much global CSS that one can foresee using. (Update: There's also only so many things you can pick up on during development.)

As the project goes on, we all add a lot of page-specific `class` and `ID` selectors in HTML for styling and layout **with external CSS files**. (I am defining "page-specific CSS" here a little differently — I don't mean `<style>` inside the `<head>` but, for example, I typically give the `body` of each page a unique ID.)

- By and large, the most common HTML elements that will need
  page-specific changes are on elements like: `p`, `img`, `figure`,
  `figcaption`, `section`, `article`, `div`, etc.
- The page-specific changes most commonly use the following CSS
  properties: `padding`, `margins`, `font` properties, `widths`,
  `heights`, etc.

The question is — once a project is complete, and a big CSS file has been created — what's the **best approach to go back and reduce/remove what's unnecessary?** I mean, by combining CSS rules to be global and catch-all as much as possible (*without breaking anything*).

---

P.S. In HTML5, I try to avoid setting a class or ID to an element unless I have to. I believe that general rules can work really well (for the most part, of course).

Comment: The best way is to stay on top of this as you're writing your app, and not produce a "monster CSS".

Comment: In hindsight, that's always the case. But please see my very first line, i.e.: there's only so much foresight one can have.

Comment: It's not about foresight, it's about organizing your CSS as you go.

Comment: Yes, and it's not bad to do — don't see why it seems you downvoted my question because of that. Also, I think you're misunderstanding what I meant by "monster CSS" — it simply means a big CSS file, as most sites have. Most of it is necessary, however, it'd be interesting to figure out ways to reduce it post-completition (especially if multiple developers are working on the same site). Definition: Organizing your CSS as you go for future benefits such as these **is foresight**.

Comment: @Baumr There isn't really a specific way of doing it, just looking back over the code and recognising what you can optimise. You could always inspect elements all your elements and make sure nothing is being overwritten, if so, delete them!

Answer (score 6):

You should read Johnathan Snook's book [Scalable and Modular CSS](http://smacss.com/) for some insight for dealing with this problem. Not using classes on elements is your prerogative, but it's one of the most powerful tools we have for writing maintainable CSS. [Harry Roberts' "Big CSS"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-BX4N8egEc) presentation also provides some powerful insight and tools for so-called "object-oriented" css. So, my first bit of advice is to start utilizing classes in your markup.

I understand the concern for wanting to write semantic html, which is probably why you shy away from using classes - but classes on html elements do not detract from semantics, as long as you write them intelligently. In fact, they usually (always, really) provide more information about an element.

The difficult part is writing classes that *are* semantic, that describe the function of an element rather than the presentation. [Yahoo's Design Pattern Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/) is a really good place to get examples of semantic class names, as well as a great resource for many useful design patterns in web architecture.

**As a brief tl;dr:**

1. When organizing your CSS, use the cascade to your advantage. Set up
   your reset first, followed by global styles - these are generic
   layout styles applied directly to element selectors. Next, write
   your modules - these are your classes and they should be
   element-agnostic.
2. Avoid qualifying your classes with tag selectors. In order to
   provide documentation and guidance for anyone else maintaining your
   site, you should use "quasi-qualified selectors" instead

   For instance, rather than:

   ```
   div.carousel { /* style information here */ }
   ```

   instead write:

   ```
   /* div */ .carousel { /* style information here */ }
   ```

   With this technique, you can provide documentation for how you
   expect your components to be used, without actually qualifying them
   and raising the specificity (thus destroying their modularity).
3. Beyond all else, remember this: balance your specificity.
   Well-architected CSS sits right at the cusp of the general and the
   specific. You need to use classes in order to make your CSS modular
   and reusable, but you also need to avoid bloat.

Comment: What a great first post! Welcome to SO

Comment: I have been meaning to read SMACSS for a while, thanks for the push — I'll get on it when I have some more time. With regards to #2, why do you suggest to avoid qualifying classes with tag selectors?

Comment: Harry Roberts explains it better than I ever could, but basically: it limits modularity and is less efficient. What if you, or someone else using your CSS framework wants to apply a module to a different, more appropriate html element in the future? By keeping classes separate from specific elements, your CSS is more future-proof. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-BX4N8egEc&t=1595

Comment: No problem, you're welcome (pun intended)

Comment: For some reason, I can't stand to believe that nobody can think of a more compelling reason to avoid *ever* qualifying class selectors with type selectors than "it limits modularity and is less efficient". Not all CSS was built to be 100% modular, and performance is hardly ever a concern unless you're building heavy web interfaces.

Comment: By the same logic, we should stop using `a:link, a:visited` and go with `:link, :visited` instead, because HTML guarantees that the only possible element type that will match either pseudo-class is `a`, thus making that type selector completely superfluous when styling HTML. Why hasn't anybody come up with that yet?

Comment: Agree with the rest of the answer, though. I'm not saying to always use type selectors - I just happen to think that there are cases that do justify qualifying other selectors with a type selector, especially classes, e.g. specificity, similar element types sharing a class (such as `ul` and `ol` sharing the same class). The `a:link, a:visited` case, though, ought to provide some food for thought.

Answer (score 2):

## Look for duplicate styles

In a large code base, you're bound to have selector and/or style duplication. Try to find as many as you can.

There are a number of ways to do this, but you might want to find a tool for your platform (or a web tool) that will scan your CSS for selector and style duplication. There are a ton out there, but to get you started, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117862/tool-to-remove-repeated-css-selectors) has a number of suggestions, including Dust-Me and CodeBeautifier.

## Look for patterns in your duplications

This may take some sleuthing, particularly if there's no indication as to what a given element is, but try to find patterns. Have you defined half a dozen different navigation lists that all share largely the same styles (`display: inline-block`, `float: left`, margins, padding, etc)? Even if some of them have a different left margin, you can still set a default margin for the outliers to override, and have a "navigation" class that sets these defaults.

For simple effects (colors, margins, etc), you can combine them in selector lists (`a, span, p {}`). For more complext effects, see the OOCSS section, below.

This doesn't just go for individual items, but for pages, as well. If you're finding that you *have* to have page-specific styling, see if there are patterns between them. So instead of having things like `#page-2` on your body, you could have something more like `#theme-wide` or something else that's a little more modular and descriptive, and allows you to consolidate code.

## Make sure you're leveraging the Cascade

Part of the beauty of CSS is that you can set generic things and override them later using specificity. However, it's easy to get caught up in specificity wars and end up with mile long selectors and heavy usage of `!important`, especially if you have any third-party code that has any kind of base styling. So make sure you're not doing stupid things like `#page-2 div.navigation ul.nav li a` when `.navigation a` or `#page-2 .navigation a` would suffice.

Andy Clarke has [an awesome explanation](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) for figuring out CSS specificity and comparing two selectors, if you don't have a good grasp on how it works.

## Sprinkle in some OOCSS principles

I'm not a huge advocate of object-oriented CSS (what I've seen tends to go overboard on the CSS classes and whatnot, and I'm a bit of a purist when it comes to having semantic HTML), but it does have some good ideas, and can help make things more modular. For example, I have a particular complex effect (complex in that several selector blocks and pseudo-elements are involved) that I'd like to use on any type of container. I don't really care what the container is. Therefore, I create a class, with a meaningful name, that is more or less self-contained, that I can then stick on any element I wish, and the CSS takes care of the rest.

When considered carefully, and used wisely, you can modularize some of your more complex styles without peppering your HTML too much with classes of questionable semantics.

## Move IE-specific styles to separate stylesheets instead of using hacks in your main sheet

IE hacks are ugly, nonsensical (unless the person reading the file has them memorized), and may cause unintended side effects in browsers. Unless there's a reason you *have* to keep something in the main stylesheet, it's probably a good idea to just put them in their own stylesheets and use conditional comments. While conditional comments are technically non-standard code, it *is* intentionally there, and for the purpose of tweaking Internet Explorer (and technically, non-IE browsers, too). They're not going anywhere any time soon, so don't be afraid to make use of them.

Doing this also avoids having to set a style that other browser recognize, only to unset it later using a syntax a certain version of IE doesn't recognize, or vice versa. Yes, it causes a little more overhead for IE users, but users of IE9 and later won't likely have to download any extra stylesheets, so unless your traffic rivals that of Google or Facebook, and most of it is coming from IE6 or 7 on a dial-up connection (ie - the cost of the extra call for select versions of IE is greater than the cost of the extra CSS for every browser and your maintenance costs), the one extra call will likely be negligible.

## For the future...

They say an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure, and in this case, especially, they're right. While you certainly can't foresee everything, there are things you can do from the start to make your life easier in the long run. Remember, whether it's front end code like CSS or business logic code like Java, some poor fool is going to have to maintain it and will likely not know the code very well (even if that poor fool is you, a year or two down the road). Therefore, it's often a good idea to look at your entire lifecycle to ensure you're not missing important foundational improvements that would avoid costly large-scale refactoring in the first place.

### Use a CSS preprocessor

It might be a good idea for your future projects to leverage something like SASS or LESS, which can make large CSS easier to maintain for a number of reasons. One of the big reasons is that it allows you to nest styles, so instead of

```
nav {}
nav li {}
nav li a {}
```

you get

```
nav {
  li {
    a {}
  }
}
```

which will naturally group things more easily. Additionally, you can separate out things like reset styles into their own files while you develop, then combine and minify everything before pushing them out to production. You can also create base styles (color themes, standard gutter widths, etc) and store them in variables to be used throughout your CSS code, so that the values are stored in one place, making it easier to maintain.

### Take a good look at your design methods/choices

Is there a sound reason you have so much page-specific styling to begin with? If you're on the same site (same branding, etc), it's generally considered best practice to maintain a consistent look and feel. Changing margins, paddings, fonts, etc. on a page-by-page basis can remove from that consistency. Users probably won't know exactly *what* is different, but they will know something is up, and will think less of your site for that reason, even if they can't pinpoint it.

Are you not using a reset/normalization mechanism? If not, that may contribute to it, as you find that your CSS is largely dealing with inconsistencies between browsers. It's often good to set everything (or at least certain elements) to a common, sane, starting point from which to build. Whether you nuke it all with a `*{margin:0; padding: 0;}` call or use something selective, like Normalize.css, or something somewhere in between, such as Eric Meyer's CSS reset, is ultimately up to you. However, using *something* that gives you a consistent starting point for the different elements will go a long way in keeping extraneous CSS (in this case, things to compensate for slight differences between the base styles of, say, Chrome and Firefox) at bay.

Questions like the above can help you determine the root causes of some of your maintenance costs, and possibly help you reduce them in the long run.

Comment: Great insight, very interesting. Thank you! But I think that browser defaults are there for a reason, so I stay away from CSS resets and use things like Normalize.css instead

Comment: @Baumr - While I admittedly worded it rather ambiguously, I would consider normalize.css to fall into what I originally intended for a "reset mechanism", hence the line about setting everything *or select elements* to a *common, sane* starting point. Whether a developer goes all the way like some of the "scorched earth" resets do, or whether they use something more selective, like Normalize.css, is up to the developer. Rewording now.